# Map Fails to load on Chrome on OnePlus 5T

Tags: here-api

I'm using the Here JavaScript web SDK and everything is working fine on every device and browser combination on BrowserStack.  However, on a physical OnePlus 5T device running Chrome 77.0.3865.116 the map fails to load with the stack trace below in the console.

What I see is that the container for the map including map controls is displayed, the two markers that are added to the map are also briefly shown.  Then the screen appears to redraw and the markers disappear leaving a grey, empty map with just the UI controls.

On the same device running Firefox, there are no issues.  The stack trace is:

```
WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost
mapsjs-core.js:377 Tangram [error]: Style: error compiling program for style '0_icon_library' (program key 'program') {texture: "icon_library", blend_order: 1, draw: {…}, mix: Array(1), name: "0_icon_library", …} TypeError: Failed to execute 'shaderSource' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLShader'.
    at Function.Zl.disabled.Wl.createShader (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:215834)
    at Function.Wl.updateProgram (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:214896)
    at f.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:208515)
    at Object.getProgram (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:255275)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:507122)
    at t (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:506861)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:507018)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:506274)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:504451)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:504035)
Jr @ mapsjs-core.js:377
getProgram @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
t @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
$k.V @ mapsjs-core.js:286
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:333
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
mapsjs-core.js:377 Tangram [error]: Style: error compiling program for style '0_shields' (program key 'program') {blend_order: 1, draw: {…}, mix: Array(1), name: "0_shields", mixed: {…}, …} TypeError: Failed to execute 'shaderSource' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLShader'.
    at Function.Zl.disabled.Wl.createShader (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:215834)
    at Function.Wl.updateProgram (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:214896)
    at f.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:208515)
    at Object.getProgram (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:255275)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:507122)
    at t (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:506861)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:507018)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:506274)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:504451)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:504035)
Jr @ mapsjs-core.js:377
getProgram @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
t @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
value @ mapsjs-core.js:377
$k.V @ mapsjs-core.js:286
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:333
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
requestAnimationFrame (async)
Xj @ mapsjs-core.js:234
zm @ mapsjs-core.js:332
n.Jh @ mapsjs-core.js:334
mapsjs-core.js:377 Tangram [error]: Style: error compiling program for style '0_text-blend-order' (program key 'program') {blend_order: 1, mix: Array(1), name: "0_text-blend-order", mixed: {…}, animated: false, …} TypeError: Failed to execute 'shaderSource' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLShader'.
    at Function.Zl.disabled.Wl.createShader (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:215834)
    at Function.Wl.updateProgram (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:214896)
    at f.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:208515)
    at Object.getProgram (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:255275)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:507122)
    at t (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:506861)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:507018)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:506274)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:504451)
    at l.value (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:504035)
```

I'm not sure of the best way to report this, hence posting here.  Happy to raise as a proper issue if someone provides me with the way to do so.

EDIT
Having looked into this error message with MapBox one cause is too many browser tabs open running WebGL but this occurs with only a single tab open

Comment: could you please try to clear the cache if any, also try to go for updated version for chrome on device. please report if the issue still persists

Comment: Hi - cache clearance has no effect and this is using the latest Chrome available on the Play Store

Comment: could you please test again on this device because JS API was improved and Chrome was update, and provide us please again a stack trace. Thank you

Comment: Hi - yes, seems to be okay now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After improvements of JS API the issue "WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost" **is not reproducible any more**.